# The positioning of Mathematica or Wolfram Language

Tags: discussion

I only work from time to time with Mathematica so sometimes I notice I am behind in version or the latest news. The Mathematica programming language is now called Wolfram Language (WL), right? Is Wolfram positioning WL as a general purpose programming language? If so, then the type of questions coming in will certainly change. I noticed that there is also a Wolfram Language Forum? Is that a competitor of Mma SE, how should I see this, has it affected MMa SE at all? - I would love to see Mma making headway as a general programming language.

Comment: wow... you're like almost [3 years late](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1074/5)! :P

Comment: That is the most unfriendly comment I ever had on SE. - And for what it is worth The Wolfram Language Forum is a fairly recent site, certainly not established in 2013.

Comment: How is that in any way unfriendly? If you see the question I linked to, Wolfram Community (also called Wolfram Language Forum) was indeed established by mid 2013 since we were talking about it! [Here's](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6947359#6947359) a chat comment from Nov 2012, so it's been around at least since then. Issues re: competition were brought up there as well. We've also had another discussion on [Wolfram Language](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1152/5) and what it means for [mathematica.se] and the language in general, etc.